# Issue related to textfield and datepicker

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I have an issue related to hide and show the datepicker view when click on textfield...Actually I have 2 textfields..Here is my problem image...

**Problem**

datepicker show and hide when click on textfiled...it should show on begin editing and hide on end editing...

[image]

At 1st time when we click on "textfield 1" its working good, but as soon as it `resignFirstResponder` and make 2nd field to respond, the problem occurs.

**CODE**

```
func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    self.datepicker.alpha = 0.0
    self.datepicker.hidden = false
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3, animations: { () -> Void in
        self.datepicker.alpha = 1.0
        self.conDateHeight.constant = 100.0
        self.datepicker.addTarget(self, action: Selector("dataPickerChanged:"), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)
    })
    return true
}

func textFieldShouldEndEditing(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3, animations: {
        self.datepicker.alpha = 0.0
        }, completion: {
            (value: Bool) in
            self.conDateHeight.constant = 0.0
            self.datepicker.hidden = true
        })
    return true
}


func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    if textField == self.txtToDate {
        txtToDate.resignFirstResponder()
        txtFromDate.becomeFirstResponder()
    }
    else if textField == self.txtFromDate {
        txtFromDate.resignFirstResponder()
        txtToDate.becomeFirstResponder()
    }
    return true
}
```

> When I hide keyboard after 1st textfield and then enter in second textfield its ok...otherwise the problem is as it is

Comment: Why you don't try to set input view as datepicker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Batter to use date picker as input view

```
UIView *viewDateInput = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0,[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width, 200)];
[viewDateInput setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
self.pickerDate = [[UIDatePicker alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, viewDateInput.frame.size.width, viewDateInput.frame.size.height)];
self.pickerDate.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDate;
[viewDateInput addSubview:self.pickerDate];
[self.pickerDate addTarget:self action:@selector(dateChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
[self.txtDate setInputView:viewDateInput];
```

Function For date Change

```
- (void)dateChanged:(id)sender
{
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
    NSString *currentTime = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:self.pickerDate.date];
self.txtDate.text = currentTime;
}
```